# Which one to use Value vs std::string in cocos2d-x V3 C++?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-2.x

According to http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Value,

Value can handle strings as well as int, float, bool, etc.

I'm confused when I have to make a choice between using

```
std::string
```

or

```
Value
```

In what circumstances should I use Value over std::string, and vice versa??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the `Value` object. As written in the documentation you linked to:

> cocos2d::Value is a wrapper class for many primitives ([...] and std::string) plus [...]

So really `Value` is an object that wraps a bunch of other types of variables, which allows cocos2d-x to have loosely-typed structures like the `ValueMap` (a hash of strings to `Values` - where each `Value` can be a different type of object) and `ValueVector` (a list of `Values`).

For example, if you wanted to have a configuration hash with keys that are all strings, but with a bunch of different values - in vanilla C++, you would have to create a separate data structure for each type of value you want to save, but with `Value` you can just do:

```
unordered_map<std::string, cocos2d::Value> configuration;

configuration["numEnemies"] = Value(10);
configuration["gameTitle"]  = Value("Super Mega Raiders");
```

It's just a mechanism to create some loose typing in C++ which is a strongly-typed language.

You can save a string in a Value with something like this:

```
std::string name = "Vidur";
Value nameVal = Value(name);
```

And then later retrieve it with:

```
std::string retrievedName = nameVal.asString();
```

If you attempt to parse a `Value` as the wrong type, it will throw an error in runtime, since this is isn't something that the compiler can figure out.

Do let me know if you have any questions.